# Invalid identifier, cakephp 2.5 relationship

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.5, and I get an error message :

> Warning (2): ociexecute(): ORA-00904: "USER"."UF": invalid identifier  [ROOT\app\Model\Datasource\Database\Oracle.php, line 432]

At the controller I do have this conditions asking for the user uf column

```
//Verify controller
$paginate['conditions']['User.uf'] = $this->passedArgs['Verify.uf'];
$paginate['contain'][] = 'User';
```

At the model I do have a belongsTo property with the user relationship:

```
//Verify Model
public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'Usuario',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        ),
```

How can i relate the User Model with the Verify Model?

Comment: Is the Containable Behavior loaded? https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html Try to set debug level to 2 and have a look at the generated SQL. There should be a JOIN on the users table.

Comment: I just add public $actsAs = array('Containable'); in the model and it starts to work, Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I just added this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the Containable behavior to the model class.

```
$actsAs = array('Containable');
```

You can also load the behavior on the fly:

```
$this->Verify->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
```